# Actualizar android-studio

Tags: android-studio

Muy buenas comunidad, tengo la siguiente actitud, poseo el android studio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y ahora realizando el checkupdate, me dice que se actualiza a:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi consulta es la siguiente si realizo dicho proceso, podrá interferir en lo que tengo realizado a la fecha, es decir la codificación (java) y en los xml formularios de diseño, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Es actualización no modifica el código de tus proyectos, eso únicamente corresponde al Android Studio (IDE). **`Nota:`** Debes tener mucho cuidado cuando realizas actualizaciones de las librerias/dependecias que utilizas en tu código.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aclaración, si el miedo que tengo es que puede haber incompatibilidad en las dependencias, y en si en el código o en los xml que uno tiene ya listos, si el problema que tengo con mi versión que trabajo en android no puedo trabajar con el View Model, no me importa las librerías que deben tener por ejemplo la del ViewModelProvider, que sin esa no puedo seguir avanzando